# Swift: check if object is not an instance of a class

Tags: swift

Checking if an object "is-a" class is easy and clean -

```
if someObject is MyClass {...}
```

However, the only way I found for the invert seems ugly -

```
if !(someObject is MyClass) {...}
```

The parenthesis are required because otherwise the `!` "tried" to negate the object.

I know this is not a common use case, but still.
Is there another way of asking that?

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/8479 :D

Comment: As you say, it's not that common to have logic that's applicable to a set of types apart from one specific one, would it be possible to expand on your use case for this? (but to answer the immediate question – no, there's currently no shorthand way of negating `is`)

Comment: @Hamish thanks. Maybe write that as an answer...

Comment: `if someObject is MyClass == false {...}`

Comment: @noamtm I don't really feel like "no there's not" is a particularly useful answer, especially as vacawama points out, you could ditch the parens by comparing to `false` (tho IMO `!(someObject is MyClass)` is cleaner).

Comment: What's wrong with `!(someObject is MyClass)`? The exclamation mark to negate an expression is a common syntax and an assumed `is not` or `isn't` syntax claims at least the same amount of characters. @vacawama The `... == false` solution causes a warning if the compiler determines that the objects are not related.

Comment: @vadian, It is no different than `if !(someObject is MyClass) {`.  The warning doesn't happen if the thing you are testing is an `Any`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
if type(of: someObject) != MyClass.self { }
```

---

You coud define a custom operator:

```
infix operator !!

func !! <T,U> (lhs: T, rhs: U.Type) -> Bool {
    return !(lhs is U.Type)
}

"Hello" !! Int.self    //true
```

Comment: That won't work if `someObject` is a subclass of `MyClass`

Comment: That's a valid point, but I didn't see such a requirement in the question